# Centrar div debajo de otro div en CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo este código HTML:

```
<body>

<div class="center">
En este sitio web se usan los siguientes servicios:

<dl>
  <dt>S3</dt>
  <dd>- Usaremos un S3 Bucket.</dd>
</dl>

Para comenzar, por favor haga clic en uno de los dos botones que están debajo.
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button>Iniciar Sesión</button>
  <button>Registrarse</button>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* Box */
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* List of Services */
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
dd {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}
/* Button */
.btn-group {
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
.btn-group button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
    cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
    float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
/* Footer */
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Screenshot:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo alinear los botones a la derecha pero, debajo del cuadro superior?.
He intentado `.btn-group { margin: 0 auto; }` pero, no funciona.

Comment: ¿Se puede modificar el HTML o solo CSS?

Comment: @Shaz ambos si es necesario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modificando solo CSS, lo que propongo es darle las mismas propiedades de posicionamiento al contenedor de los botones y al "cuadro superior", posteriormente con flexbox alineo los botones al final (sé que hay otros métodos, pero personalmente prefiero flexbox):

```css
/* Box */
.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* List of Services */
dt {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
dd {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 1em 0;
}
/* Button */
.btn-group {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: calc(50% + 20px);
    }
.btn-group button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
    cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
    float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
/* Footer */
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
En este sitio web se usan los siguientes servicios:

<dl>
  <dt>S3</dt>
  <dd>- Usaremos un S3 Bucket.</dd>
</dl>

Para comenzar, por favor haga clic en uno de los dos botones que están debajo.
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button>Iniciar Sesión</button>
  <button>Registrarse</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Vale, ha funcionado a la perfección, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Por qué no usas la solución más sencilla y eficiente ? Flexbox

html

```
<div class="padre">
    <div class="hijo1">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="hijo2">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.padre {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

De esta forma usando flexbox. todos los elementos que estén dentro de la clase padre. estarán centrados tanto horizontalmente como verticalmente.